# Add data to an array in assembly for solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging, arrays, assembly, data-types

Hi I'm trying to make a function in assembly inline with following purpose:

**Given:** An array in the blockchain with names (= bytes32[] _documentHashes).

**Asked:** Find which indexes are equal to the name that I search (= bytes32 _searchHash) and return them in an array (= uint[] result)

I have the following code, with some comment to clarify my logic. Following [Topic](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/30192/problem-using-created-array-from-assembly) has helped me to produce this code:

```
function arrMke() public{ // Some test data
    bytes32[] arrMke;
    arrMke.push(0X10);
    arrMke.push(0X20);
    arrMke.push(0x10);
    arrMke.push(0X40);
    uint[] arrResult = search(arrMke,0X10);
}

function search(bytes32[] _documentHashes, bytes32 _searchHash) public returns (uint[] result){
    assembly {
        let len := mload(_documentHashes) // Load the length (first 32 bytes)
        let counter := 0 //count each time data in the _documentHashes == _searchHash
        result := mload(0x40) // 0x40 is the address where next free memory slot is stored in Solidity.
        let i := 0 // uint i for the loop
        loop: //start loop
        let docHash := mload(add(_documentHashes, add(0x20, mul(i, 0x20)))) // docHash = _documentHashes[i], data offset = 0x20 (1st 32 is reserved for size) & i*32 to pickup the right index
        if eq(docHash, _searchHash) { // condition if(docHash == _searchHash)
            counter := add(counter,1) // increment counter by 1
            mstore(add(result, 0x20), counter) // (re)Set size of the result array each time the condtion is true
            mstore(add(result, add(0x20, mul(counter, 0x20))), i) // add data to the array, data offset = 0x20 (1st 32 is reserved for size) & i*32 to pickup the right index 
        }
        i := add(i,1) // increment for loop
        jumpi(loop, lt(i,len)) // stop loop when the lenght of _documenthashes is reached
        mstore(0x40, add(result, add(0x20, mul(counter, 0x20)))) // Update/return the result array ofsset + length of the data (=i*32)
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

1. I don't get the debugger in remix running. The "Solidity locals" screen is empty:

[image]

2. uint[] arrResult = search(0x0,arrMke,0X10); does'nt want to compile:

[image]

3. Question:

1) How can I watch (see the data in) my variabeles, especially uint[] result? Because I'm not sure if my assemblercode is correct at all. 
2) Why do I get this compile error & how can I fix it?

Thanks for your help!

Tshy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues I've found

- Declare `arrResult` as memory reference (default is storage)
- Length of an array is stored at `result+0`, it was stored at `result+0x20`
- Don't use `let` inside a loop it will create a new variable every time (It appears to be a bug in the compiler)
- Incremented counter before use, resulting index `result+0x20+0x20*(counter+1)`
- Update `result` length once at the end to save some gas

This should work as expected

```
function arrMke() public returns (uint[]) { // Some test data
    bytes32[] arrMke;
    arrMke.push(0X10);
    arrMke.push(0X20);
    arrMke.push(0x10);
    arrMke.push(0X40);
    uint[] memory arrResult = search(arrMke,0X40);
    return arrResult;
}

function search(bytes32[] _documentHashes, bytes32 _searchHash) public returns (uint[] result) {
    assembly {
        let len := mload(_documentHashes) // Load the length (first 32 bytes)
        let counter := 0 //count each time data in the _documentHashes == _searchHash
        result := mload(0x40) // 0x40 is the address where next free memory slot is stored in Solidity.
        let i := 0 // uint i for the loop
        let docHash := 0
        loop: //start loop
        docHash := mload(add(_documentHashes, add(0x20, mul(i, 0x20)))) // docHash = _documentHashes[i], data offset = 0x20 (1st 32 is reserved for size) & i*32 to pickup the right index
        if eq(docHash, _searchHash) { // condition if(docHash == _searchHash)
            mstore(add(result, add(0x20, mul(counter, 0x20))), i) // add data to the array, data offset = 0x20 (1st 32 is reserved for size) & i*32 to pickup the right index 
            counter := add(counter, 1) // increment counter by 1
        }
        i := add(i,1) // increment for loop
        jumpi(loop, lt(i,len)) // stop loop when the lenght of _documenthashes is reached
        mstore(result, counter) // (re)Set size of the result array each time the condtion is true
        mstore(0x40, add(result, add(0x20, mul(counter, 0x20)))) // Update/return the result array ofsset + length of the data (=i*32)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ismael, thanks for the remarks. All useful feedback! I receive the expected result ("0": "uint256[]: 3" with input 0x40 as searchHash)

Comment: Ismael, any idea how I can see the data of my variables in the debugger (watch function)? I don't see any (see screenshot in Problem 1st point)

Comment: I do not use the debugger very much, I think it works for simple variables like uint or byte32, for arrays it doesn't appear to work. For assembly I look at the stack, the top changes frequently but you can recognize the variables below.